# TYPO3 how to remove usergroup from user

Tags: typo3, extbase

TYPO3 how to remove usergroup from user by code ?

```
$user = UserUtility::getCurrentUser();

$vipGroup = $this->userGroupRepository->findByUid($this->extConf['vipGroupUid']);
$user->removeUsergroup($vipGroup);
$this->userRepository->update($user);
$persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager');
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

that not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should. Note that the FronendUser is cached in the session. If you're removing the group on the currently logged in user, this will have no effect until the next login.

Answer (score -1):

It does not! TYPO3 just silently does not make the update, no error message nothing.
The best way to verify that it does really not work is to check the Database.
As TYPO3 seems to silently not do updates or even inserts when using the standard repository functions I have gone over to writing my own for important things. They then use SQL circumventing all the TYPO3 overhead.
I know this defeats the purpose of having an abstracted database layer, but since the abstraction is dangerously malfunctioning I have decided to go this path as the data is more important that an abstract concept!